# Combinatorics Cheat Sheet

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, factorial

I want to put together a combinatorics cheat sheet and I want to get started with the basic counting formulas. After some reviewing one could easily conclude that **order** and **repetitions of the elements** in sequences of interest could be a good start to categorize counting formulas.

I have started by reviewing the basics (cf. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation/)):

> A weaker meaning of the term "permutation" (...) designates those
>   ordered arrangements in which **no element occurs more than once**, but
>   without the requirement of using all the elements from a given set.
>   Indeed, this use often involves considering arrangements of a fixed
>   length $k$ of elements taken from a given set of size $n$, in other
>   words, these **$k$-permutations of $n$ are the different *ordered*
>   arrangements of a $k$-element subset of an $n$-set (sometimes called
>   variations in the older literature)**. (...) The number of such is
>   denoted variously by such symbols as $P^n_k$, and its value is given
>   by the product: $$ P(n,k) = P^n_k = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!} $$

In summary, we can permute all of the elements of a set $S$ with cardinality $|S| = n$. We can also take a variation, in where we permute only $k$ elements out of the $n$ possible elements from $S$. Here, we account for order but disregard repetitions.

> This usage of the term "permutation" is closely related to the term
>   "combination". A $k$-element combination of an $n$-set $S$ is a $k$
>   element subset of $S$, the elements of which are not ordered. By
>   taking all the $k$ element subsets of $S$ and ordering each of them in
>   all possible ways we obtain all the $k$-permutations of $S$. The
>   number of $k$-combinations of an $n$-set, $C(n,k)$, is therefore
>   related to the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ by:
>   $$ C(n,k) = \frac{P(n,k)}{P(k,k)} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,k!} $$

So, for combinations we now disregard order.

Finally, we have (cf. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation/)):

> Ordered arrangements of the elements of a set *S* of length *n* where
>   **repetition is allowed** are called *n*-tuples, but have sometimes been
>   referred to as permutations with repetition although they are not
>   permutations in general. They are also called words over the alphabet
>   *S* in some contexts. If the set *S* has *k* elements, the number of *n*-tuples over *S* is: $$ k^n $$

Therefore, it seems like the following preliminary version of the cheat sheet makes sense:

- YES order, YES repetitions: $k^n$
- YES order, NO repetitions: $P^k_n$
- NO order, NO repetitions: $C(n,k)$

However, what about the final case? What if we want to disregard order but preserve repetitions? I am inclined to take
$$
P(n,n) = n!
$$
but I am not sure.

Comment: I think you want $\binom{n+k-1}k$.

Comment: Also, in the line for $C(n, k)$, the implication signs should be replaced by equals signs.

Comment: To typeset an implication symbol use `\implies`. At any rate, those should be equals signs anyway.

Comment: @bof: Yes. The question has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

[Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation),
[Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement),
[Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination),
[Pigeonhole-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle),
[inclusion exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
etc.

Answer (score 0):

The case you wish to add is combinations with repetition, the number of ways of distributing $n$ identical objects into $k$ distinct boxes.  The number of ways the objects can be distributed to the boxes is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones.  For instance, if $n = 9$ and $k = 4$, 
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 4$, $x_3 = 0$, and $x_4 = 3$.  Therefore, the number of such solutions is the number of ways we can select which $k - 1$ of the $n - k + 1$ positions (for $n$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs) will be filled with addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$
This number also counts the number of ways of selecting $n$ objects from $k$ types of objects when there are at least $n$ objects available of each type.